# Change Unicode Input from Hex to Decimal

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, unicode, unicode-entry

Okay, so, I already know about the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>+<kbd>Hex</kbd> method of inputting unicode characters.

I would like to change this just slightly to accept the decimal value of the desired unicode character rather than the hex value. I want to do this because

- Coming from <kbd>Alt</kbd> codes, I already have the decimal values of the characters I want to use memorized and do not want to relearn (or worse, use mental math to convert to) hex
- Given that I know how to type and my left hand is occupied holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> I have to hunt-and-peck for characters my right hand doesn't know how to find unconsciously

Is there a simple way to change this? If not, where is the behavior of presuming hexadecimal input defined (as specific as you can get)?

Assuming there's not, I just want to be pointed in the right direction. I'm willing to modify, build, and reinstall pretty much any package.

Alternatively, would there be a workaround possible, like binding an alternative key combination (something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Decimal</kbd>) to a function that would convert the decimal to hex and simulate the "correct" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>+<kbd>Hex</kbd>) keyboard input?